# I cannot use the keyboard shortcut <ctrl>+<alt>+<enter> in matlab running in emacs running in screen

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, gnu-screen, matlab

In my usual setup, I use use matlab-emacs to run Matlab through the Emacs  GUI. I run Matlab and emacs on a Linux server, and use ssh and X forwarding so this all shows up on my local Ubuntu laptop.

I would like to further complicate this setup by running emacs in screen. This mostly works with the notable exception that the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> which tells Matlab to run a block of code, doesn't seem to do anything. I presume this shortcut is getting sent perhaps somewhere locally on my own machine? I notice the menu bar at the top of my terminal on my laptop changes when I try to run this command.

Does anyone have a clever suggestion for how I can get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run Matlab code blocks as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminals transmit characters¹, not keys. When you press a key or key combination like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, the terminal has to translate it to a character or character sequence. There aren't nearly enough characters to represent all keys, so most such combinations are transmitted as escape sequences: a sequence of characters starting with the escape character.

There's no universal standard for the escape sequences, though there are some common conventions. For example, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>*key*</kbd> often sends the escape character followed by the character or escape sequence for *key*; but there's no standard for what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> sends. Some terminals are configurable, some have hard-coded escape sequences.

See also [Problems with keybindings when using terminal](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/problems-with-keybindings-when-using-terminal/13957#13957) for a more detailed explanation as well as possible solutions with Xterm.

If you can't get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to be transmitted through your favorite terminal, you can choose a different key binding. Figure out what command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> runs by pressing `C-h c C-M-return` when you're using Matlab in a GUI Emacs. Then type `C-h w matlab-foo RET` where `matlab-foo` is the command name; this will tell you what key(s) `matlab-foo` is bound to. If there isn't a binding that you can type conveniently, add one to your init file, with something like

```
(defun my-eval-after-load-matlab ()
  (define-key matlab-mode-map [f9] 'matlab-foo))
(eval-after-load "matlab" '(my-eval-after-load-matlab))
```

For `"matlab"`, substitude the name of the Lisp file that defines the `matlab-foo` command. To find out what that is, type `C-h k C-M-return`; this tells you something like “C-M-return runs the command matlab-foo, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `matlab.el`”. The name of the Lisp file is that last bit on the line, minus the `.el` part. For `matlab-mode-map`, substitute the name of the keymap; this is generally the name of the major mode (`C-h v major-mode RET`, “Its value is matlab-mode”) plus `-map` at the end.

Alternatively, do you really need to use Screen? If you're only using it so that Emacs survives the disconnection, this isn't actually necessary. Start Emacs as a daemon (`emacs --daemon`), and connect to it remotely over SSH by running `emacsclient -c` to open a new GUI frame. You can open and close GUI frames on multiple displays, and Emacs will keep running even if the displays come and go.

¹  <sub>Actually bytes, but that bit is irrelevant here.</sub>